# EasyNetQ Exclusive queue disposing

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm using EasyNetQ / Rabbitmq i'm creating 10 exclusives queues, that's wait for a message, unfortunatly all theses queues are disposed before the end for my prog.

I'm suspecting a `BasicCancel` event.

But i can't even know why did i received it.

What are reasons for RabbitMQ to send a `BasicCancel` event ?

Regards

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: As requested, some code would be good. But another thing to check, if you are using the AdvancedBus, make sure you are not setting the durable property to false : https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/The-Advanced-API